# "INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR" when installing an app on BlueStacks

Tags: installation, apk, bluestacks

I need some help with installing an app that I want to use using the BlueStacks App Player. I've downloaded the APK and I have a problem when I was trying to install it. I tried deleting it and install back a new one but it didn't work.

The error message says:

> Apk Installation failed: INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Can anyone suggest me some ways to fix it?

[image: error message]

Comment: Based on [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66771), it seems it only occurs on emulator with wrong time set. Have you set correct date & time *and timezone* on BlueStacks?